# Stable way to set Max duration for MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent, video-capture

I learned from few post here that MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT for capturing video, could work only from versions 2.2 ,but i am using Samsung Galaxy S II which is of 2.3.3 version . The below code seems to have no effect for max duration.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 2000);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION,true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

If its device specific,then is there a workaround for this issue.

Comment: (agreed with @ermau) still am also facing the same problem on htc evo and htc incredible devices. Works fine on nexus one. Any one knows what is the solution to it.

Comment: Same here, works well on Nexus-s but not with htc desire-hd...
I set the limit to 30 sec.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation states that `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` is in **seconds**.

Setting it to `2000` would be  **33 minutes**, try 2:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you set EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY to zero, It is create mms and not works as a video recorder:[EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY)

If you want set value of EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, then you have to change EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY  value to 1.